# Nested defaultdict(list) grouping

Tags: python

I have a block of result rows and I am trying to group them into two levels of nesting `[{key: value[{key:value[]}]}]`. The values are non-unique at the top level keys.

I've been trying to use `defaultdict`, but have not had success grouping at both levels given non-uniqueness. Iterating over the data may be better but I also haven't had success with that.

Starting data:

```
data = 
[{'Name': 'Bob', 'Time': 12, 'Place': 'Home'}, 
{'Name': 'Bob', 'Time': 11, 'Place': 'Home'}, 
{'Name': 'Jerry', 'Time': 5, 'Place': 'Home'}, 
{'Name': 'Jerry', 'Time': 11, 'Place': '-----'}, 
{'Name': 'Jerry', 'Time': 11, 'Place': 'Work'}]
```

Final desired data:

```
[{"Name": "Bob", "Details":[{"Place":"Home", "Time":[12, 11]}]}, 
{"Name": "Jerry", "Details":[{"Place":"Home", "Time":[5]}, 
                             {"Place":"-----", "Time":[11]}, 
                             {"Place":"Work", "Time":[11]}]}]
```

Comment: Maybe using update in a for loop? Kind of compact, but the gist being: `[x.update({'Details': [{...}, {...}]}) for x in data];print(data)` The other part being keeping track of `seen` by using a `set()` or another dictionary. And using a `x.pop` on the dictionary to place those keys into a temp dictionary that then gets added to the details list value?

Answer (score 2):

You could group by the `Name` and `Place` using `itertools.groupby`,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data
[{'Name': 'Bob', 'Time': 12, 'Place': 'Home'}, {'Name': 'Bob', 'Time': 11, 'Place': 'Home'}, {'Name': 'Jerry', 'Time': 5, 'Place': 'Home'}, {'Name': 'Jerry', 'Time': 11, 'Place': '-----'}, {'Name': 'Jerry', 'Time': 11, 'Place': 'Work'}]
>>> sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x['Name'], x['Place'])) # sorting before grouping as suggested by @wwii, because The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with groupby(). Please see (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> y = itertools.groupby(sorted_data, lambda x: (x['Name'], x['Place']))
>>> for group, grouper in y:
...   time_ = [item['Time'] for item in grouper]
...   name, place = group
...   d[name].append({'Place': place, 'Time': time_})
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Bob': [{'Place': 'Home', 'Time': [12, 11]}], 'Jerry': [{'Place': 'Home', 'Time': [5]}, {'Place': '-----', 'Time': [11]}, {'Place': 'Work', 'Time': [11]}]})
>>> pprint.pprint(dict(d))
{'Bob': [{'Place': 'Home', 'Time': [12, 11]}],
 'Jerry': [{'Place': 'Home', 'Time': [5]},
           {'Place': '-----', 'Time': [11]},
           {'Place': 'Work', 'Time': [11]}]}
```

If you need the exact structure you showed then,

```
>>> f_data = []
>>> for key, value in d.items():
...   f_data.append({'Name': key, 'Details': value})
... 
>>> pprint.pprint(f_data)
[{'Details': [{'Place': 'Home', 'Time': [12, 11]}], 'Name': 'Bob'},
 {'Details': [{'Place': '-----', 'Time': [11]},
              {'Place': 'Home', 'Time': [5]},
              {'Place': 'Work', 'Time': [11]}],
  'Name': 'Jerry'}]
```

Comment: You should ensure  `data` is sorted before *grouping*.

Comment: @wwii May i ask why ?

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby): `Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.`. ... Try it on an unsorted list/iterable.

Comment: @wwii Ah, i see the problem. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: If `data` is a list it can be sorted in place: `data.sort(key=...)`

Comment: OP wants a list of (separate) dictionaries, one for each `Name`.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the data; group by `'Name'`, group that result by `'Place'`; extract the times.

```
import operator
name = operator.itemgetter('Name')
where = operator.itemgetter('Place')
time = operator.itemgetter('Time')

data.sort(key=lambda x: (name(x),where(x)))
result = []
for name, group in itertools.groupby(data,key=name):
    d = {'Name':name, 'Details':[]}
    for place, times in itertools.groupby(group,key=where):
        times = map(time, times)
        d['Details'].append({'Place':place, 'Time':list(times)})
    result.append(d)
```

---

I like to use `operator.itemgetter` instead of a lambda function if it will be used more than once. Just my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to solve it with a bit of help from Pandas. Have a look:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'Name': 'Bob', 'Time': 12, 'Place': 'Home'}, 
{'Name': 'Bob', 'Time': 11, 'Place': 'Home'}, 
{'Name': 'Jerry', 'Time': 5, 'Place': 'Home'}, 
{'Name': 'Jerry', 'Time': 11, 'Place': '-----'}, 
{'Name': 'Jerry', 'Time': 11, 'Place': 'Work'}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

#Take the unique names only
names = df["Name"].unique()

#This list will hold the desired values
new_list = []

# Iterate over names
for n in names:
    # Make subset off the data set where name is n
    subset = df[df["Name"]==n]
    # Get Unique Places in the subset
    places = subset["Place"].unique()
    # This will hold the details
    details = []
    # Iterate over unique places
    for p in places:
        # Get times from subset where place is  and convert to list
        times = subset[subset["Place"]==p]["Time"].tolist()
        # Append to details list
        details.append({"Place":p,"Time":times})
    # Add the details in new_list as the format you preferred
    new_list.append({"Name":n, "Details":details})

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea with `defaultdict` plus iteration. The only slightly tricky bit is making a nested `defaultdict`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def timegroup(data):
    grouped = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
    for d in data:
        grouped[d['Name']][d['Place']].append(d['Time'])
    for name, details in grouped.items():
        yield {'Name': name,
               'Details': [{'Place': p, 'Time': t} for p, t in details.items()]}
```

(I like to use generators for things like this, because sometimes you just want to iterate over the results, in which case you don't need a list, and if you do need a list it's easy to make one.)